# Fail to disabled “Security Warning” window in Webbrowser control

Tags: c#, wpf

I tried to disabled security popup, but it still prompting.

Error Popup:

```
Do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely This webpage contains content that will not be delivered using a secure HTTPS connection, which could compromise the security of the entire webpage.”“This page contains both secure and nonsecure items. Do you want to display the nonsecure items?”
```

WPF:

```
<WebBrowser Name="wbGateway" Width="700" Height="600" 
                        OverridesDefaultStyle="False"
                        ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
                        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"></WebBrowser>
```

Code:

```
private void wbGateway_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
        {
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new 


RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);
}

    public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Side-note: You should really do some validation, if you don't SSL becomes pretty useless. For example you could white-list a certain certificate fingerprint.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The problem is the page is out of my control, what I am order to do is to put the page in the webbrower control and disable security and javascript error.

Comment: Certificate validation is a client-side concern. You don't need to change the server to get good validation.

Comment: because the web page is not properly done, that is the reason it prompted the security alert.

Answer (score 0):

Here,we go with the solution: I run it on the Browser_Navigated event as the underlying activeX component is null until then.

**Ref:**https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4f686de1-8884-4a8d-8ec5-ae4eff8ce6db/new-wpf-webbrowser-how-do-i-suppress-script-errors?forum=wpf

```
    private void Browser_Navigating_1(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
    HideScriptErrors(Browser,true);

    }

public void HideScriptErrors(WebBrowser wb, bool Hide)
{

    FieldInfo fiComWebBrowser = typeof(WebBrowser).GetField("_axIWebBrowser2", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    if (fiComWebBrowser == null) return;
    object objComWebBrowser = fiComWebBrowser.GetValue(wb);

    if (objComWebBrowser == null) return;

    objComWebBrowser.GetType().InvokeMember(
    "Silent", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, objComWebBrowser, new object[] { Hide });

}
```